# How to find dates based on mathematical calculations

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sumifs, tabular

I have an Excel sheet with three columns:

1. List of duplicate IDs of customers.
2. Amount spent by them in $.
3. Date of the spend.

The sheet is sorted on the first column i.e. List of duplicate ID's of customers. Every time a customer spends something it is recorded in the Excel sheet with the ID, spent amount and date of spend.

I want to extract the 'ID' (1st column), 'Collective amount spend' (2nd column) and 'date' (3rd column) on which a particular customer has reached the cumulative spend of $500 for all those customers.

Can anyone help in how it can be done easily in MS Excel?

```
**Customers**        **Amount**        **Date**
00000000001             $200           12/01/15
00000000001             $300           12/08/15
00000000001             $100           12/25/15
00000000002             $200           12/03/15
00000000002             $400           12/09/15
00000000003             $200           12/11/15
00000000003             $100           12/15/15
```

This is some sample data to simplify the question. I would like to get a sheet as follows:

```
**Customers**        **Amount**        **Date**
00000000001             $600           12/08/15
00000000002             $600           12/09/15
```

Let's say we are updating the data as follows:

```
**Customers**        **Amount**        **Date**
00000000001             $200           12/01/15
00000000001             $200           12/08/15
00000000001             $100           12/25/15
00000000002             $200           12/03/15
00000000002             $400           12/09/15
00000000002             $100           12/13/15
00000000003             $200           12/11/15
00000000003             $100           12/15/15
```

And the result we get back now should be as follows:

```
**Customers**        **Amount**        **Date**
00000000001             $500           12/25/15
00000000002             $700           12/09/15
```

Comment: It would appear that your expected result has a typo. Customer 00000000001 should have a cumulative value of $500 on 12/08/15 rather than $600

Comment: @DeanOC The cumulative value needs to be the sum of all the transactions made which also considers 12/25/15 $100 spend. But the date needs to be the one they first crossed the threshold.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for the answer as well as the appreciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `**Customers**` is in A1 and your data is sorted by date ascending within `**Customers**` ascending, then please try in D2:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B)
```

and in E2:

```
=IF(AND(SUMIFS(B$2:B2,A$2:A2,A2)>=500,SUMIFS(B1:B$2,A1:A$2,A2)<500),C2,"")
```

with both copied down to suit. Then filter on ColumnF to select non-blanks.

Here [SUMIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php) is being used to provide the cumulative total by `**Customers**`.

[SUMIFS](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumifs.php) here is being used twice to detect the transition across $500 - once summing up to the current row and once to the row immediately above the current row. When the transition is detected the corresponding date is copied.

Comment: This solution seems to work fine for me! Thanks :) I am still not clear how this thing worked. If you could help me with a resource I can understand the logic of the formulas, it would be great help. Thanks once again. :)